# Howto rotate pdf within webview

Tags: ios, pdf, webview, rotation

I have a webview showing a pdf page.
How can i rotate the pdf by 90 degrees, so it is shown correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to display that PDF and nothing else on the web view, you could rotate the entire web view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    webView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 0.0);

    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DegreesToRadians(90));
    webView.transform = rotationTransform;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.If I do this I receive the error: Property ‘anchorPoint‘ cannot be found in forward class object ‘CALayer‘

Comment: Try this instead:     webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2); E: use only this line